# How to check if appened cron job has no errors while executing?

Tags: cron

I have added a three different executable scripts - bash, php, python scripts on to a crontab as cronjob

How would I check that three executable scripts are not giving any errors or not having any errors while executing from cron tab ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, is this 3 different cron entries, or is three scripts sharing the same cron entry?   For the latter (one cron entry for three scripts), do this (for a cron run every minute):

```
* * * * * /bin/bash script.sh && /usr/bin/php script.php && /usr/bin/python script.py
```

The php will only run if the bash succeeds.  Likewise, the python will only run if both the bash and php script succeed. If you need all scripts to run regardless if one of them fails, have each job run from their own cron entry.  In which case, do this:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash script.sh 2>>/var/log/script.sh.errors && echo "Bash Completed Successfully" >>/var/log/script.sh.success
* * * * * /usr/bin/php script.php 2>>/var/log/script.php.errors && echo "PHP Completed successfully" >>/var/log/script.php.success
* * * * * /usr/bin/python script.py 2>>/var/log/script.py.errors && echo "Python Completed successfully" >>/var/log/script.py.success
```

In the second example, errors log to a separate file.  Scripts can return a exit code 0 (i.e. "Success") even if there are errors (for instance, if the script actually has an exit 0 statement at the end of it).  Thus, it's best to try to capture errors as the script runs, then capture a successful exit code, if it exits successfully.

Comment: These are separate script entries into cron tab. The scripts are not dependent. I only have to check if scripts which i appended to crontab, while executing, is not giving any errors. In that way, if scripts in cron tab gives any error I can remove them immediately rather than allowing them to keep executing with errors.  
So according to your second solution, I need to log errors inside a log file, read that log files for any error? Thanks !